# React/jQuery Sign Up Form app - How can I simplify this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

everyone this is my first post here on StackOverflow, on my journey to becoming a full stack developer. I am using FrontEnd Mentor to practice and I solved the solution with this code. I am just looking for tips on how to simplify this code or how to make it more effecient. I know there was a simpler way to achieve this, but I can not figure out how.

The goal of the code was to produce an error icon, red text underneath that says that you cannot leave it blank. Once they enter information and click submit, the error styles would go away.

Follow up question, how would I immediately remove the error styles when they start typing?

Thank you everyone! I hope to be able to contribute here as well as I become a better programmer.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import ErrorIcon from "../images/icon-error.svg";
import $ from "jquery";

function Form() {

  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({fName: "", lName: "", email: "", password: ""});

  function emailIsValid(email) {
    return /\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(email);
  }
  emailIsValid("azanku19@gmail.com")

  function checkFields() {
    if (inputValue.fName === "") {
      $(".error-icon.fName").show();
      $(".error.fName").show();
      $(".sign-up-form-input.fName").css("margin-bottom", "0px");
    } else {
      $(".error-icon.fName").hide();
      $(".error.fName").hide();
      $(".sign-up-form-input.fName").css("margin-bottom", "20px");
    }

    if (inputValue.lName === "") {
      $(".error-icon.lName").show();
      $(".error.lName").show();
      $(".sign-up-form-input.lName").css("margin-bottom", "0px");
    } else {
      $(".error-icon.lName").hide();
      $(".error.lName").hide();
      $(".sign-up-form-input.lName").css("margin-bottom", "20px");
    }

    if (!emailIsValid(inputValue.email)) {
      console.log(inputValue.email);
      $(".error-icon.email").show();
      $(".error.email").show();
      $(".sign-up-form-input.email").css("margin-bottom", "0px");
    } else {
      console.log(inputValue.email);
      $(".error-icon.email").hide();
      $(".error.email").hide();
      $(".sign-up-form-input.email").css("margin-bottom", "20px");
    }

    if (inputValue.password === "") {
      $(".error-icon.password").show();
      $(".error.password").show();
      $(".sign-up-form-input.password").css("margin-bottom", "0px");
    } else {
      $(".error-icon.password").hide();
      $(".error.password").hide();
      $(".sign-up-form-input.password").css("margin-bottom", "20px");
    }
  }

  function handleChange(event) {
    const {value, name} = event.target;

    setInputValue((prev) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        [name]: value
      }
    });
  }
  console.log(inputValue.fName);
  return (<div className="sign-up-container">
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6 sign-up-left">
          <h1>Learn to code by watching others</h1>
          <p>See how experienced developers solve problems in real-time. Watching scripted tutorials is great, but understanding how developers think is invaluable.</p>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6 sign-up-right">
          <div className="top-message">
            <p>
              <span>Try it free 7 days
              </span>{" "}
              then $20/mo. thereafter</p>
          </div>
          <div className="sign-up-form">
            <div className="form">
              <div className="input-container">
                <input onChange={handleChange} className="sign-up-form-input fName" placeholder="First Name" name="fName" type="text"></input>
                <img className="error-icon fName" src={ErrorIcon}/>
                <span className="error fName">First Name cannot be empty</span>
              </div>
              <div className="input-container">
                <input onChange={handleChange} className="sign-up-form-input lName" placeholder="Last Name" name="lName" type="text"></input>
                <img className="error-icon lName" src={ErrorIcon}/>
                <span className="error lName">Last Name cannot be empty</span>
              </div>
              <div className="input-container">
                <img className="error-icon email" src={ErrorIcon}/>
                <input onChange={handleChange} className="sign-up-form-input email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" type="text"></input>
                <span className="error email">Looks like this is not an email</span>
              </div>
              <div className="input-container">
                <img className="error-icon password" src={ErrorIcon}/>
                <input onChange={handleChange} className="sign-up-form-input password" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password"></input>
                <span className="error password">Password cannot be empty</span>
              </div>
              <button onClick={checkFields} type="submit">Claim your free trial now</button>
              <p className="tns-notice">By clicking the button, you are agreeing to our {" "}
                <a href="">Terms and Services</a>
              </p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>);
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: Removing jQuery would simplify it

Comment: The Code Review stack exchange is the place to ask for code reviews. There are several ways this could be greatly simplified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am just looking for tips on how to simplify this code or how to make it more effecient.

First, you can use the jQuery method `toggle` and see if fName is empty or not using the length:

```js
$(".error-icon.fName").toggle(inputValue.fName.length == 0);
```

Plus, you can have one inline if statement for the css:

```js
$(".sign-up-form-input.fName").css("margin-bottom", (inputValue.fName.length == 0)?"0px":"20px");
```

However, I like things clean so we can just create a boolean to use it with them, ending with something like this

This will give you this code:

```js
let isFNameEmpty = (inputValue.fName.length == 0);
$(".error-icon.fName").toggle(isFNameEmpty);
$(".error.fName").toggle(isFNameEmpty);
$(".sign-up-form-input.fName").css("margin-bottom", (isFNameEmpty)?"0px":"20px");
```

Or, you can even simplify futher:

```js
let isFNameEmpty = (inputValue.fName.length == 0);
$(".error-icon.fName, .error.fName").toggle(isFNameEmpty);
$(".sign-up-form-input.fName").css("margin-bottom", (isFNameEmpty)?"0px":"20px");
```

However, we can be even more effective since you are modifying three selectors, so how about we create a function (we can improve it later)?

```js
function toggleErrorSignUpForSelector(selector, state){
  $(".error-icon.".concat(selector)).toggle(isFNameEmpty);
  $(".error.".concat(selector)).toggle(isFNameEmpty);
  $(".sign-up-form-input.".concat(selector)).css("margin-bottom", (isFNameEmpty)?"0px":"20px");
}
```

*Note: I put them back into separated lines because it easier to read.*

Next, I think you should break down your code into reusable components.

For example, the code below, together with whatever would do the validation on them, could be turn into a reusable component. I haven't work with react in a while but I think its possible

```
<div className="input-container">
    <input onChange={handleChange} className="sign-up-form-input fName" placeholder="First Name" name="fName" type="text"></input>
    <img className="error-icon fName" src={ErrorIcon}/>
    <span className="error fName">First Name cannot be empty</span>
</div>
```

This will give you flexibility since the form is one component, the inputs would be other component, and the submit button would be also a separate component.

By separating components you could, for example, create your own UI/UX library with reusable elements which would help you in the future to you and your team.

Let me know if this advice help you out.

Comment: Why use jQuery at all? It doesn’t make much sense.

Comment: @DaveNewton, that is the decision of the developer who asked the question. I am just showing him how he can simplify his code and making it more efficient. I agree that he shouldn't need to run jQuery and should be able to do it with pure ReactJS; therefore, I advice him to investigate about creating custom components in ReactJS. We need to have in consideration his current level and guide him to improve them.

Answer (score 0):

use packages like validatorjs to simplify the validation and a formError variable

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({fName: "", lName: "", email: "", password: ""});
const [formError, setFormErrors] = useState({fName: "", lName: "", email: "", password: ""});
```

In the form

```
<input type="text" name="fname" onChange={(e) => setInputValue({...inputValue, fname: e.target.value})}/>
<div>{!!formError.fname && formError.fname}</div>
//Same for other fields
```

For Validating and submission

```
const submitHandler = ()
{
let error = {};
if(inputValue.fName.length==0)
error.fName = "Invalid Name";
//Similarly validate the other variables

setFormErrors(error);

if(error.length == 0)
{
//Do the submission thing here
}

}
```

Hope you get the idea and avoid using jQuery with React

EDIT:-
You can use ternary operator to change the css classes like

```
<input type="text" className={`fname ${!!formError.fname?'errorField':''}`} />
```

I have not tested it but it should probably work.

Comment: This is a really good tip, thank you. To clarify why is it bad to use jQuery with React? Is it because I should use tools already available in React to accomplish something like this? Also maybe I am not understanding fully, but how would this code allow me to edit the class settings as well?

Comment: React uses its own virtual DOM to show its content whereas Jquery is used for manipulating the real DOM. The virtual DOM in react cannot be manipulated directly but instead it is re-rendered again with changed content. The re-rendering is done everytime a state variable is changed. So using both would just make things complicated.

Answer (score 0):

We can can do this in react way or we have other ways but according to your structure we can try this solution instead of checking one by one,
we can use some other javascript methods

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import ErrorIcon from "../images/icon-error.svg";
import $ from "jquery";

function Form() {
 const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({fName: "", lName: "", email: "", password: ""});

const [errors, setError] = useState({}) 

function emailIsValid(email) {
    return /\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(email);
  }
```

emailIsValid("azanku19@gmail.com")

```
function checkFields() {
    Object.keys(inputValue).map(key => {
      if ((key === "email" && !emailIsValid(inputValue.email) || !inputValue[key]) ) {
        setError({...errors, [key]: true});
        $(`.sign-up-form-input.${key}`).css("margin-bottom", "0px");
      } else {
        setError({...errors, [key]: false});
        $(`.sign-up-form-input.${key}`).css("margin-bottom", "20px");
      }
    });
  }



function handleChange(event) {
    const {value, name} = event.target;

    setInputValue((prev) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        [name]: value
      }
    });
  }
  console.log(inputValue.fName);
return (<div className="sign-up-container">
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6 sign-up-left">
          <h1>Learn to code by watching others</h1>
          <p>See how experienced developers solve problems in real-time. Watching scripted tutorials is great, but understanding how developers think is invaluable.</p>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6 sign-up-right">
          <div className="top-message">
            <p>
              <span>Try it free 7 days
              </span>{" "}
              then $20/mo. thereafter</p>
          </div>
          <div className="sign-up-form">
            <div className="form">
              <div className="input-container">
                <input onChange={handleChange} className="sign-up-form-input fName" placeholder="First Name" name="fName" type="text"></input>
                {errors.fName && <><img className="error-icon fName" src={ErrorIcon}/>
                <span className="error fName">First Name cannot be empty</span></>}
              </div>
              <div className="input-container">
                <input onChange={handleChange} className="sign-up-form-input lName" placeholder="Last Name" name="lName" type="text"></input>
                {errors.lName && <><img className="error-icon fName" src={ErrorIcon}/>
                <span className="error fName">Last Name cannot be empty</span></>}
              </div>
              <div className="input-container">
                {errors.email && <img className="error-icon email" src={ErrorIcon}/>}
                <input onChange={handleChange} className="sign-up-form-input email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" type="text"></input>
                {errors.email &&
                <span className="error email">Looks like this is not an email</span>}
              </div>
              <div className="input-container">
                {errors.password && <img className="error-icon email" src={ErrorIcon}/>}
                <input onChange={handleChange} className="sign-up-form-input password" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password"></input>
                {errors.password &&
                <span className="error password">Password cannot be empty</span>}
              </div>
              <button onClick={checkFields} type="submit">Claim your free trial now</button>
              <p className="tns-notice">By clicking the button, you are agreeing to our {" "}
                <a href="">Terms and Services</a>
              </p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>);

}

export default Form;
```